# How to add new CVS in eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, cvs, lan

I have developing one PHP project using eclipse locally. Now i need to share this project to another system in LAN.
Can anybody help me as how to do this..?
How to add CVS in eclipse..?

Comment: sorry this isn't the place where you ask this kind of question.

Comment: oh..!..sorry.. I am newbie to this site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on Project and choose Team -> Share Project
2. Select a repository type(for your needs CVS)
3. Create new/use existing repository location and do accoriding to a wizard

   [see this!](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-117.htm)

Comment: when i create a new CVS it asks 'host' and 'repositary location'. Here  which host name i need to give and whats the 'repositary location'...?

Comment: In the Host field, type the address of the host (for example, "teamsamples.com"). In the Repository path field, type the path for the repository at the host address (for example, "/home/cvsroot/repositoryName"). In the User field, type the user name under which to connect. In the Password field, type the password. In the Connection type field, select the type of CVS connection for the repository (The default is pserver). Leave Use Default Port enabled.

Comment: i read these instructions in the above link which was you posted. But i am not clear the host name. Which host name i need to give...? May i give any name..?

Comment: host name is host address (e.g. http://198.168.1.20 or http://xxx.xxx ), see this article- should be helpful http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000659.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I know what you mean, but... You have to commit your folder with project. Right click on it and choose SVN - commit. You don't have to touch your eclipse to do that.